# Typescript - string url to object type in ts

Tags: typescript

How to make string url to object type in ts ?

sample code :

```
type KeyUrl<T> = T extends `/${infer U}` ? U : never;
type TUrl<T> = { [k in KeyUrl<T>]: string };

// --------------------------------------------- this line work
const url = "/path";
const obj = {} as TUrl<typeof url>;
obj.path // work;

// --------------------------------------------- this line error
const url = "/path/path2";
const obj = {} as TUrl<typeof url>;
obj.path // Property 'path' does not exist;
obj.path2 // Property 'path2' does not exist;
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `${infer U}` is greedy and it eats up all the string.

So for `/path/path2` it will get the entire string as it doesn't split it. You need to take this into account when creating defining `KeyUrl`. Something like this should work:

```
type KeyUrl<T> = T extends `/${infer U}/${infer R}` ? U | KeyUrl<`/${R}`> : T extends `/${infer U}` ? U : never
```

What this does is that it takes the `path` and checks if there is one segment or more and then it calls the `KeyUrl` with the remaining path.

You can check a more complex example [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIFUBOAbAPAFQHxQLxQyggA9gIA7AEwGcoADAegBIBvAS3IDMIkoEBfZuy48oAJX50oAfj5QAPrHjJ0jVhLo4AXASKkKNekI7deAqbIRQd5CADceAWABQoSARWYc+FlADaANZQHEqIqF4AujrUwEgcAOZQ-ADcLi4AxgD25DFQAK6oAIx4UABEDGAAhsAAFqWpzlk5wFCZAEYAVsU+-FCVtBiebhCZnPlFWA3tXQB0VbVQDAxQAO6ZSAENGdm5BSgATCXl8zUV1TX79dvNrZ2HPX0DQ+AjY3v7ky7T+3PnUF93X61fZpRo7Fp7ADMRzOtVhFwY1EyAFsIFcwTdptCHv0POFhqNxihIZ9nFigTV-mTOpCKSDqR1aUjUUA)